# filesAdded and filesSubmitted events

Tags: flow-js

I'm using the [flow.js](https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js) library for file uploads in a project.

I'm confused about the parameter `files` received by `filesAdded` and `filesSubmitted` events. Would the parameter always contain files corresponding to a particular directory on disk (in case of directory uploads) and a single file (in case of file uploads) or can it contain files from seemingly *unrelated* uploads as well?

To give you an example, consider the scenario where a user adds two files in sequential fashion. 
Can the `filesAdded` and `filesSubmitted` events be triggered with the `files` parameter containing both these files even when they were part of *unrelated* uploads?

The problem arises when you have multiple upload sections on a page, and you use a single instance of `Flow` to handle all uploads. In this case, if files uploaded on distinct upload sections appear together in events like `filesAdded` or `filesSubmitted`, then it mixes up your files belonging to separate upload actions. One solution is creating a new `Flow` instance for every upload section on a page, but I wanted to understand the behavior `filesAdded` and `filesSubmitted` and whether the behavior would permit one to solve the problem using just one `Flow` instance.